# Open Image for PictureBox - C#

Tags: c#, picturebox, openfiledialog

I don't know what's wrong here! It opens up a "OpenFileDialog", it loads up the image in the PictureBox but the image isn't streched. Please help! Thanks :)

```
    private void browsePic_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openPicture.Filter = "PNG|*.png|JPG|*.jpg;*.jpeg";
        if(openPicture.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            pictureBox2.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
            pictureBox2.Image = new Bitmap(openPicture.FileName);
        }
    }
```

Comment: set the picture box size to auto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the SizeMode-Property of the PictureBox as you need.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.sizemode(v=vs.110).aspx

```
PictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
```

Comment: In like 6 mins because it says "You cannot accept an answer in 6 minutes" :)